# Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio this morning added external libraries to my project. Now when building my project I get

```
Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4 for debug
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @acabezas Now answered.

Answer (score 8):

> Does anyone know what this means?

Some dependency of the project has directly declared a dependency on a version of Android.

## To fix

To locate the offending dependency do the following, then ideally, tell the authors of the library about their error. You can also explicitly avoid the problem while waiting for a fix:

Run `./gradlew app:dependencies`
and locate the line or lines that say:

```
+--- com.awesome:someawesomelibrary:1.0.0.0
|    +--- com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4
```

If this output is too long to find it, remember you can pipe it out to a text file by adding `> out.txt`

Now locate your gradle import of `com.awesome:someawesomelibrary:1.0.0.0` and exclude `android` like so:

```
compile ('com.awesome:someawesomelibrary:1.0.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
}
```

Comment: Excellent! BTW, a single comma is missed after "1.0.0.0".

Comment: :-D Exactly, sorry!